# Check did select file Or no, in input:file

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, upload

How can know, if select(`Choice` Or `Browse...`) file in `input:file` run some code with php?

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userfile[]" valign="baseline">
</form>


if(select file){
    run my code
}
```

**Update:**

I use of [Multiple Uploads with JQuery and Code Igniter](http://www.mitesdesign.com/blog/open-source/multi-upload-jquery-code-igniter) , when that i don't select file, output `print_r($_FILES['userfile']);` is:

> Array ( [error] => 4 [name] => [size] => 0 [tmp_name] => [type] =>
>   [key] => userfile )

`[error] => 4` is -> You did not select a file to upload.

If i select file, have following error in case i have in `input:file` this: `name="userfile[]"`:

`Message: Undefined index: userfile` in here:`print_r($_FILES['userfile']);`

**Update 2:**
I use from these Controller but if don't select a file, in the here `if ( ! $files )` return is false and give error. i want if user did not select file does not get error with a if

```
class Upload extends Controller {
    function Upload()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {    
        $this->load->view('upload_form');
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
   if($_FILE('userfile')){
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; // server directory
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; // by extension, will check for whether it is an image

        $config['max_size']    = '1000'; // in kb
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->load->library('Multi_upload');

        $files = $this->multi_upload->go_upload();

        if ( ! $files )        
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $files);
            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
 redirect('inse/show');
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  if (isset($_FILES['my_file_input'])) {
    // your code
  }
?>
```

**NOTE:** you descripted a wrong input type if i get you right - file input should use this signature:

`<input type="file" name="my_file_input" />`

**NOTE:** the form the file input is located within should have its enctype set to "multipart-form-data" (or something like that).

**UPD:** i may be wrong, but here's come controller from the module you have specified:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload extends Controller {
    function Upload()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {    
        $this->load->view('upload_form');
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; // server directory
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; // by extension, will check for whether it is an image

        $config['max_size']    = '1000'; // in kb
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->load->library('Multi_upload');

        $files = $this->multi_upload->go_upload();

        if ( ! $files )        
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $files);
            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }    
}
?>
```

If you still do not get any satisfying results, try `var_dump($_FILES);` and find out how the files are stored.

Comment: To debug it, try creating a form, uploading a file and then show contents of complete $_FILES array using print_r($_FILES);

Comment: @AliciaCibrian Yeah, and if you are not submitting your form with JS, you should have a `<input type="submit" value="send me" />` input =)

Comment: Please see my update in post. @shybovycha i use `<input type="submit" />`

Comment: @AliciaCibrian Should you use `$_FILES['userfile[]']` ? ;) Try output the whole $_FILES array

Comment: @shybovycha - Not different, still there is same errors in update my post.`Message: Undefined index: userfile[]` . i use http://www.mitesdesign.com/blog/open-source/multi-upload-jquery-code-igniter

Comment: @shybovycha - I use from these Controller but if don't select a file, in the here `if ( ! $files )` return is false and give error. i want if user did not select file does not get error with a `if`, Please see my update 2 in my post.

Comment: @AliciaCibrian so maybe you better remove the code giving you an error? ;) E.g.: `if ( ! $files ) { /* YOUR_CODE_HERE */ }` =)